# & (ampersand) char in $_SESSION() array on var_dump()

Tags: php

I have a `index.php` with a `start_session();` at the top.

Then if you click on a menu item it calls a `include();` page *(lets say page B)*. There is no `start_session();`
at the top of that page because I thought because its included I can omit it.

in this *page B* there is a `AJAX` call to call a scripts page related to *page B*. On this page I would like to use a stored `$_SESSION();` variable containing the username to do some things. I do start the page with...

> ```
> if(session_id() == '') {
>     session_start();
> }
> ```

When I do a `var_dump($GLOBALS);` on this scripts page it contains

> ```
> '_SESSION' => &
>     array (size=2)
>       'username' => string 'mo' (length=2)
>       'administrator' => string '0' (length=1)
> ```

My question is, What is the ampersand **&** 's chars meaning in this case?

Can I use the `$_SESSION();` variables as normal in this case?

Comment: whats with the down vote???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It's means that it's a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference. 
The ampersand (&) back references the array stored under the `_SESSION` key in the $GLOBALS array, when you try and access `$_SESSION` super global.